# Understanding the retrival of Certificates on a server

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I have made a simple console app that loops through all the Certificates on a Machine

```
private static X509Certificate2 GetSpecifiedCertificate(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation)
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates;


    if (certs.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("found {0} certficates", certs.Count));

        for (int i = 0; i < certs.Count; i++)
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = certs[i];
            Console.WriteLine(cert.Thumbprint);
        }
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("found no certficates at all");

    return null;
}
```

using `StoreName.CertificateAuthority` and `StoreLocation.LocalMachine` as the variables, on my Windows Server 2008R2, I only get 3 Certificates even though there are many more  installed

console app output:
[image]

installed certificates under the `CertificateAuthority` store location
[image]

> How do I get the missing ones?

I specially wan to retrieve the [Apple Certificate](http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) one to sign files, but no matter how I install the public certificate, I can not retrieve it from a store loop...

> Do I always need to restart the machine? Is there a special trick to get them?

Comment: After a first look it seems you are doing everything right, StoreName.CertificateAuthority should show you the Intermediate CAs that can be seen on your screenshot. Did you try diplaying the names of your certificates instead of the thumprint? Maybe knowing which ones are missing will help.

Answer (score 1):

How did you open the certificate window? I think you are looking at the certificates under your account instead of the computer account. However, the code queries certificates from the computer account, which usually has less certificates installed than your account.

To open the certificates window for the computer account,

1. Execute mmc at command prompt.
2. File | Add/Remove Snap-in.
3. Add Certificates.
4. Choose Computer account.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it should work with loading the "CertificateAuthority" store and fetching it from there, so it's kinda weird.

However, according to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx

It should be possible to load the Apple certificate like this:

```
var appleCert = new  X509Certificate2("appleRoot.cer");
```

Just to get you started.